# Problem with indexing on dynamic tables jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a datepicker in a dynamic table where each field is added with a button. Everything is fine, but each ID has a unique index. H
ow to do so that you do not manually set these index, but here, only that the loop itself counts and assigns values to each input in this column, no matter what index.

What working

```
          jQ("[id^='RequestDateone[0]").datetimepicker({
           timepicker:false,
           formatDate:'Y/m/d',
           maxDate:'+1970/01/01',//yesterday is minimum date(for today use 0 or -1970/01/01)
          });
```

I tried do like this:

```
  jQ('[id^="RequestDateone["]').datetimepicker.each(function (index, item)
```

MY HTML : `<input type="text"  data-timsupport="datepicker" name="RequestDatetwo" id="RequestDatetwo"    class="small" />`

Answer (score 0):

As `id` should be unique, you can use `class` attribute instead. So lets say that you put `class="datetime-input"` and then you can query every input with that class and init datetimepicker on them.

```
jQ('input.datetime-input').each(function(){
  jQ(this).datetimepicker({...});
})
```

Comment: But i can not add class ="" to input show its wrong `Attribute class redefined`

Comment: You should add this class to the datetime cell template. You probably try to set the class dynamically, but the attribute is already there. Try to use `element.setAttribute('class', element.getAttribute('class') + ' datetime-input')`

Comment: Im not sure i good understood . Could you show all code in your answer